# Access Violation while calculating a pointer

Tags: c++, windows, memory

I'm quite afraid the question is really, really simple, but even thou I'm starting to grip the idea of pointers, hints from experienced users shorten the time I need to spend on it to understand everything. Ive got a simple example, I won't go into details what its supposed to do later on, because I think my mistake is something very basic. I'm getting:

**Exception thrown: read access violation.
_First was 0x815110.**

When executing this code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"

#pragma comment(linker, "/SECTION:.data,RWE")

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {

    DWORD dwProcessID = 0;

    cout << "Looking for game process..." << endl;

    while (dwProcessID == 0) {
        dwProcessID = GetProcessID(L"PathOfExile.exe");
        Sleep(100);
    }

    std::cout << "Game Client found" << std::endl;

    printf("dwProcessID = %p\n", dwProcessID);

    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, dwProcessID);
    MODULEENTRY32 module;
    module.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);
    Module32First(snapshot, &module);

    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, dwProcessID);

    HANDLE hToken = NULL;
    if (!OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken))
        printf("Failed to open access token\n");

    if (!SetPrivilege(hToken, SE_DEBUG_NAME, TRUE))
        printf("Failed to set debug privilege\n");


    printf("PoE base address = %p\n", module.modBaseAddr);

    BYTE jmp[] = "\xBA\x00\x00\x80\x3F\x89\x10\x89\x16\xE9\x00\x00\x00\x00";

    BYTE *dwMaphack = (BYTE*)(module.modBaseAddr + 0x4D5110);
    cout << dwMaphack << endl;

    *(DWORD*)&jmp[10] = (DWORD)(dwMaphack - jmp) - 6;

    DWORD dwOldProt;

    VirtualProtectEx(hProcess, (LPVOID)dwMaphack, 8, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwOldProt);

    // tbc

    while (1) {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The open process methods and other basic stuff are in the header and they do work fine, what I don't get is why when I change the byte pointer BYTE *dwMaphack to DWORD *dwMaphack, there's no longer an access violation error?

I'm trying to base my code on an outdated code of someones that no longer works, so the reason for doing these operations is only partially known for me, I know what it's supposed to do in programming terms, but I don't know the effect in the game, yet. I don't think it's important in terms of the error I'm getting anyway. Thanks in advance for the answers!

Comment: @RbMm, another challenge ? :-D

Comment: pointer arithmetic is based on the size of the target.

Comment: A mistake in pointer type in calculation will occur in access violation error?

Comment: Set a breakpoint and look at the values in a debugger, then try looking at the memory they point to.

Comment: the modBaseAddr address is 0x00340000, but the value is 'unable to read memory' in the debugger. Thats on the line BYTE *dwMaphack = (BYTE*)(module.modBaseAddr + 0x4D5110); After this line exception happens.

Comment: Incidentally, it is unlikely to be sensible to enable debug privileges on the target process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
cout << dwMaphack << endl;
```

This is attempting to print the value that `dwMaphack` points to, not the value of the pointer.  Since the pointer is only valid in the remote process, attempting to dereference it results in an access violation.

This works:

```
cout << (DWORD_PTR)dwMaphack << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you, it does!

Answer (score 3):

`BYTE` is an alias for `unsigned char`.

`std::cout` has an overloaded `operator<<` that accepts an `unsigned char*` pointer as input and prints it as a character string (as stated by Harry Johnston, https://stackoverflow.com/a/41538200/7376565).  So it crashes when it tries to access memory it does not have access to.

`std::cout` does not have an `operator<<` overload for `DWORD*` (aka `unsigned long*`), but it does have one for `void*`, so any non-character pointer will print just the value of the pointer itself. When you change `dwMaphack` to `DWORD*`, `operator<<` doesn't try to access the memory that `dwMaphack` points to, so no access violation occurs.

Comment: Thanks guys, that helps to sort stuff in my head!

Comment: I don't recommend changing to `DWORD *` at all. Just described the reason why the code does not crash when use `DWORD *`. I prefer to convert pointer to type like `DWORD_PTR`, `ULONG_PTR` (pointer-sized integer) if I need a value of pointer.

Comment: Ah, I'd overlooked that part of the question.  My mistake.

Comment: Guys, one more thing, If I need just the address of the dwMaphack pointer, using (DWORD*)dwMaphack is correct?

Comment: In C++ address of the variable is `&Var`. In what context do you need the address?

Comment: I would like to go to the memory address of dwMaphack in memory reading program to analyse the bytes and search for a pattern that i can scan for, so what I need is the memory address of dwMaphack, which as you've mentioned I can grab by referencing to it by &, thats correct ? :)

Comment: I think I've missed something. Doing &dwMaphack will give me memory address of the dwMaphack variable, while what I need is the value of the pointer, which is an actual memory address?

Comment: You'd better start from simple task than accessing memory from other proccess. Learn how to deal with [pointers](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/). PS. Getting value at some address: DWORD Val = \*(DWORD\*)SomeAddress. But you should understand what you do.

Comment: I partially do, but dropping myself in deep waters works best for me, therefore here I'm :) thanks for the PS!

Comment: Alex P. I'm a bit wiser now, but the path is long :-) Lets say Ive got a pointer pointing to a memory of another process (game). Am I right thinking that I cannot just dereference that pointer to get the value I want because Ive got no direct access to other process memory? What I'm doing now is ReadProcessMemory and pass the handle while having the mentioned process open, which works. All I'm asking is if I'm right thinking that I cannot swap ReadProcessMemory with dereferencing if the target is within another process memory?

Comment: @MTM: That's correct. You don't have direct access to memory of another process. So you can't simply use dereferencing. Here ReadProcessMemory does the job.

Comment: All i needed to know, for now haha. Thanks alot Alex and everyone!